# How to unite 2 columns with all non-unique or NA values, without dropping cases (keep NA, merge duplicates) in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I created a dataframe in R.  Here is a sample 4-row excerpt (actual df is 13000 rows):

```
   colA  colB
1  89    89
2  NA    NA
3  90    NA
4  NA    91
```

Where NA are empty values.  Each case contains either duplicate values for each variable, 2 empty values, or 1 empty value.

I want to unite the columns into 1 column, or create new column, where:

- Each case is preserved in the output
- If values are duplicates, value in the output is that same value (NOT applying any arithmetic - I do not want to add/multiply the values; and NOT simply pasting the values next to each other)
- If each value is NA(empty), output value is NA(empty)
- If a value is NA(empty) and the other is an actual value, output should be the actual value

This is the output I want:

```
   colC  
1  89    
2  NA    
3  90    
4  91
```

I will need to perform this on 2 columns of my 13000 row df.

Answer (score 4):

Wew can use `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   transmute(ColC = coalesce(ColA, ColB))
```